# CalDav request example

Tags: caldav

I'm building a CalDAV server (in Java, using third-party library), pls help me with this:

If the request is: return all events in a calendar whose start date is between [date1, date2], then what type of request is it? and the parameters of the request?

I intend to put a servlet for a client to query. I'm wondering if I have to make a servlet for each type of requests: `GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT (target exists),PUT (no target exists),PROPPATCH,PROPFIND,DELETE,LOCK (target exists),LOCK (no target exists), MKCOL, MKCALENDAR,UNLOCK,REPORT,FREEBUSY`

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First question: You want to use a timerange based calendar query. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791#section-7.8.1

Second question: You need only one servlet. Typically, you verwrite its default service() method to dispatch to separate handlers, one for each method (REPORT, PUT,...).